# empty().append() appending last item in loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm doing the following:

```
$('.document-content').on('input', function() {
  var headers;
  headers = $('.document-content > h2').each(function() {
    var headerId, headerText;
    headerId = $(this).attr('id');
    headerText = $(this).text();
    $('.document-outline').empty().append("<h2><a href='#" + headerId + "'>" + headerText + "</h2>");
  });
});
```

In order to avoid duplication, I added `empty()` but now only the last item in the each `loop` is being appended to `.document-outline`.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to empty it before the loop, else before adding any item you are removing the previous contents meaning all the previous items are removed thus only the last item in the loop is kept

```
$('.document-content').on('input', function () {
     var $ct = $('.document-outline').empty();
    var headers;
    headers = $('.document-content > h2').each(function () {
        var headerId, headerText;
        headerId = $(this).attr('id');
        headerText = $(this).text();
        $ct.append("<h2><a href='#" + headerId + "'>" + headerText + "</h2>");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to `empty()` the containing element outside of the loop, otherwise it is being cleared on each iteration.

```
$('.document-content').on('input', function() {
    var $headers = $('.document-content > h2'), 
        $outline = $('.document-outline').empty()

    $headers.each(function() {
        var headerId = $(this).attr('id'),
            headerText = $(this).text();
        $outline.append("<h2><a href='#" + headerId + "'>" + headerText + "</h2>");
    });
});
```

Note that I shortened the logic slightly by setting the values as the variables are declared.

Answer (score 1):

Empty it outside loop otherwise you will end with appending last elements only as everything before it will get emptied

```
$('.document-content').on('input', function() {
  var headers, 
  var outlineDoc = $('.document-outline').empty()
  headers = $('.document-content > h2').each(function() {
    var headerId, headerText;
    headerId = $(this).attr('id');
    headerText = $(this).text();
    $(outlineDoc).append("<h2><a href='#" + headerId + "'>" + headerText + "</h2>");
  });
});
```